# Fixing problems with Android Studio,Git, Api Level and the appcompat

Tags: android, android-studio

I am trying to run an android app with Android Studio, but getting a lot of errors.
The android app is available in Git and uses the API level 19.
Ill describe what I did to import it and what errors I have.

1. Downloaded Android Studio
2. Installed Android Studio, Changed the path for the Android SDK installation due to Non-Ascii chars in my windows user name(I installed the Android SDK to C:\AndroidSDK).
3. Changed the Git settings to my git.exe.
4. "Check out from VCS" - Log in and pull the developer branch.
5. Downloaded the Android 4.4.2 (API 19) with the Android SDK Manager
6. Right click on my project -> Platform Settings: SDKs -> Added the API 19 thing and changed to it
7. Project Settings: Project: Change Project SDK to Android API 19 Platform
8. Build it and run it

The error I get is one that I found many people have. But I am complelety new and couldnt really do anything with the other answers here on stackoverflow.

> Error:(4, -1) android-apt-compiler: [main] C:\Users\MyName\AndroidStudioProjects\smartreserve_01\SmartReserve\app\src\main\res\values\styles.xml:4: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar'.

I tried to fix it.
Project Structure:

1. Modules
2. +
3. Import Module
4. Added the module: "androidsdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat"
5. Clicked on my module
6. Dependencies -> +
7. Module Dependency
8. Added the appcompat thing.

But then I just get hundreds of errors that some UI element cannot be found.
I just dont know what to do anymore.
As far as I am aware the App does not use gradle.

Thanks for your help! :/
I am just a complete noob with Android Studio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know how your `styles.xml` is ... but it should be something like this ...

```
<resources>
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="AppTheme.Base">
        <!-- nothing to do here -->
    </style>
    <style name="AppTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    </style>
</resources>
```

---

You also have to add the dependencies in your `build.gradle` file.

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
}
```

Note the version might be different for you.

---

And finally in your Java class ...

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    .... code goes here
}
```

Hope this is helpful. Thanks!